# Setting up a cron job with Webmin

Tags: php, cron, webmin

I am trying to setup a Cron job using Webmin to run every 5 min.  It needs to target a .php file and run the php script in that file.  When I enter the path to the file in the "Command" field, it doesn't work.  I am just wondering what I am doing wrong, and where do I put the file path that I need the Cron job to run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

1. `System -> Scheduled Cron Jobs`
2. `Click Create a new scheduled cron job`.
3. `In Command box enter /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/path/to/your_php_script.php`
4. `Click "Times and dates selected below .." radio button`
5. `Click "Selected.." under Minutes section`
6. `Select 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55 (use control key) and click 'Save' button`.

Comment: -q mean supress HTTP header or CGI mode only, http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 23):

[image: A Visual Of The Question.]

Here Is A Visual Of Adding A New 5 Min. Int. Cron Job In Webmin version 1.610.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the "command" SLE (single line entry) field. When you reach the scheduling page, click [Run Now] to test.

By all means inspect records written (Webmin unit test) and certainly test (with a stub) the scheduling from Webmin, as some of the Webmin modules are a little flaky.

Answer (score 1):

im guessing you are running a linux environment. in that case you can run the command (through ssh/terminal) `php /path/to/file.php`.

If this works, then now the trick is to make this a scheduled command. You can do this with crontab by typing `crontab -e` This will then open a text editor which you can type something of the following:

```
@hourly php /path/to/file.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will then run the command `php /path/to/file.php` every hour and detatch the process.

This is the linux way of doing it, webmin may have a way of doing this through the web ui. maybe that is what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

goto Webmin>System>Scheduled Cron Jabs -> 'create new scheduled cron job' and as mentioned above use php command with script as parameter to exec it